# ansible become_user to an unprivileged user fails

Tags: ansible, google-compute-engine, sudo

I'm using ansible script to create a directory on a remote. This seems to  fail when I use both become and become_user. Please note that I'm using a privileged user to login the box and other commands (without become_user) seem to work fine. There are no password sets for any of the users `deploy ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

```
# This works
- name: create log directory
  file: path={{ log_directory }} state=directory owner=metax group=metax mode=0755
  become: yes 

# This fails
- name: create log directory
  file: path={{ log_directory }} state=directory owner=metax group=metax mode=0755
  become: yes
  become_user: deploy
```

Fails with error:

```
fatal: [node0]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_name": "file"}, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}
```

I've also tried to enable pipelining as described on ansible documentation:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user

Comment: install the `acl` package on the target system.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense if you are connecting with Ansible as `root`. What is the result of:
    `- command: whoami`
      `register: whoami`
      `become: yes`
      `become_user: deploy`
    `- debug: msg="{{whoami.stdout}}"`? With and without of `become_user`? Besides, why do you use `become` if you are already `root`?

Comment: Failed with same error with `become_user` and got message: 
`
ok: [node0] => {
    "msg": "root"
}
`
without become_user. It's interesting about using `become` because I'm essentially not using the actual "root" user but rather a user with `sudo` powers. That's why I imagine using `become` would be useful.  Without become and become_user I get: 
`
ok: [node0] => {
    "msg": "ankitjain"
}
`

Answer (score 1):

From the ansible documentation, you can define the method of becoming this user with:

```
become_method

at play or task level overrides the default method set in ansible.cfg, set to ‘sudo’/’su’/’pbrun’/’pfexec’/’doas’/’dzdo’
```

that means that deploy user is not in sudoers. Try something like **su**

Comment: Interesting, when I tried setting the become_method, I get another error message: {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user. For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}

But I've already setup pipelining with "Defaults !requiretty"